# How to optimize two-layer knn

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, classification

I am doing a two-layer knn.
That is, I use knn to do classification and to calculate distance I need to divide the distance vecotor X-Y into several sub-vectors and do knn on them.
Thus, the time complexity is horrible, O(#vector^2 * #sub-vector^2)
I have tried multi-thread programming, but it's still too slow.
Now I am trying C++ AMP, but I don't know how to deal with two-layer knn.

Comment: I know what is knn, but the idea of two-layer knn eludes me. Perhaps I'm not the only one. If you could elaborate what your task is and what you have done so far, you would get more help.

Comment: We usually use d = ||X-Y|| as the distance between two vectors. But what I am doing is to divide X-Y into several sub-vectors and to each sub-vector Vi, find knn sub-vectors Vi1-Vik and let d = sum(sum(Vi-Vij)). That's why I call it two-layer.